# Entity not creating table in DB

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring boot, and I Run this model.

```
package com.example.demo.Models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = true)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer priority;
   
    /* Here are all the setters and getters*/
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbdemo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Everything fine with Java.

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But in the console of my docker image of Postgres I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "user" at character 14
STATEMENT: create table user(id bigserial not null, email varchar(255), name varchar(255), priority integer, primary key (id))
```

I'm not sure how to solve it, I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please share application.properties file

Comment: `user` is a [reserved word in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), you need to chose another table name for your entity.

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Sure, I updated the question with the file.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Holy moly, yeah I rename it to `users` and it worked, thanks!!! feel free to post your answer so it helps more people, happy new year guys 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table public.user ( id serial not null, 
               email varchar(255), 
               name varchar(255), 
               priority integer, 
               primary key (id))
```

add the schema name before the table name

[image]

Comment: This is really cool, is there a way to do this but with spring code?

Answer (score 2):

user is a reserved word in Postgresql thats why it show an error
use a different word like "users" "usersId".

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the schema name in table and id fields like this:

```
@Table(name = "anomaly", schema = "schema_name")
public class Anomaly {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id",  allocationSize = 1, schema = "schema_name")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long anomalyId;
```